# Trying to get the line of code from a specific crashlog

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, core-data-migration

I'm trying to understand how to get the line of code from this line of a core data crash log (arm64)

I've been able to symbolicate it from :

0x0000000100922c94 0x10089c000 + 552084

to :

0x0000000100922c94 +[NSManagedObject(SBTMerge) objectForCode:entityName:context:mergeExisting:] + 552084 (NSManagedObject+SBTMerge.m:0)

but line 0 is the top of the file which doesn't make sense.

I've used atos and dwarfdump but I'm not able to get the line of code / offset using the load address "+ 552084"

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to symbolicate your crash log. So at least you ned .dSym file and .crash file, put this file in a single path. Then run a commands

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" 

cp -i /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash ./ 

./symbolicatecrash bug.crash > symbolicated.crash
```